# Why does the ranking page show yesterday's reputation?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, rankings

I have 810 rep on SO. When I checked my all-time rank, I saw that am having 795 rep.
But one hour ago, one of my answers was accepted. So my rep got to 810. But still the previous 795 rep is displayed in the ranking. Why is this?

Is the data of my rep not updated everywhere? [This is my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2194674/stackoverflow)

[image]

Comment: We only update these once a day.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you mean updated. :)

Comment: Indeed, I did mean that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is correct.

You will see yesterdays reputation. The leagues are not real-time and are updated once a day.